# Where is site collection administrator option in communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, groups, communication-site

Under the site permissions, for a team site I can see the site collection administration. I think this is the case because I'm the O355 group owner.

But for communication site I don't get this option. But also there's no O365 group for such a site. I have full control permission on the site.

How can I add site collection administrators to communication site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Site Collection Administrators" option in advanced SharePoint site permissions will be shown only if you are already a Site Collection Administrator (SCA) for that particular site.

New site collection administrators can be added to communication site by existing site collection administrator from SharePoint site permissions page OR by Global Tenant Administrators or SharePoint Administrators from SharePoint admin center.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for more information and detailed steps:

1. [Manage SharePoint site admins](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-administrators?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

---

**Additional**:

Existing site collection admins can also add new site collection admins programmatically. For example:

[SharePoint Online: Add Site Collection Administrator (SCA) using Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/30/sharepoint-online-add-site-collection-administrator-sca-using-power-automate/)

Comment: Ok so the site collection owner or having full control on site collection isn't sufficient permission to see site collection administrators?

Comment: Yes, correct. You have to be "Site Admin" (previously known as "site collection administrators") to "Site Collection Administrators" option. You can request SharePoint tenant admin in your company to grant you this access for the site.